# Jira upgrade 8.19.0 cannot connect to mysql 5.7.35

Tags: mysql, jira, mysql5.7

I have confluence and jira running on a standalone server.

I just upgraded confluence - no problems. It runs connected to mysql and is up as we speak on the latest version.

I just updated jira but it says it cannot connect to the database:

> Database: We've found an error in MySQL supported version!
> The database type in your dbconfig.xml is set up to MySQL 5.7 and your MySQL version is different. Consider using MySQL 5.7 database type instead
> See our documentation for more information on changing database type.

But the database config or database version never changed.

I updated the .jar from mysql-connector-java-5.1.48 to:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar
```

But still wont connect.

The dbconfig looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jira-database-config>
  <name>defaultDS</name>
  <delegator-name>default</delegator-name>
  <database-type>mysql57</database-type>
  <jdbc-datasource>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://dbserver:3306/jiradb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;sessionVariables=default_storage_engine=InnoDB</url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <username>jiradb</username>
    <password>somepassword</password>
    <pool-min-size>20</pool-min-size>
    <pool-max-size>20</pool-max-size>
    <pool-max-wait>30000</pool-max-wait>
    <validation-query>select 1</validation-query>
    <min-evictable-idle-time-millis>60000</min-evictable-idle-time-millis>
    <time-between-eviction-runs-millis>300000</time-between-eviction-runs-millis>
    <pool-max-idle>20</pool-max-idle>
    <pool-remove-abandoned>true</pool-remove-abandoned>
    <pool-remove-abandoned-timeout>300</pool-remove-abandoned-timeout>
    <pool-test-on-borrow>false</pool-test-on-borrow>
    <pool-test-while-idle>true</pool-test-while-idle>
    <validation-query-timeout>3</validation-query-timeout>
  </jdbc-datasource>
</jira-database-config>
```

Without rolling back everything I don't know what to do, has anyone else hit similar issues?

I have rolled back the entire server (complete with database) but JIRA still will not start :/ does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem on 1 of 3 instances. The solution was to add a parameter to the url, which looked completely unrelated to me. I can only look it up when I'm back at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on one of my three instances after upgrading JIRA to version 8.19.0. I have a containerized deployment, all three instances use the same JIRA image and the same MySQL image, nevertheless only one instance was affected.

For me the solution was to add the `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` parameter to the URL.

```xml
<url>jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/jira?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;sessionVariables=default_storage_engine=InnoDB</url>
```

Comment: hmm ok that is a new one to me too, thanks for sharing! It did burn too much of my time yesterday